# password in odbc connection in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, odbc, rstudioapi

In my shiny application, in `global.R` I have defined an `odbc` connection as follow :

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 DSN = 'abc',
                 Database = 'xxx',
                 UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
)
```

The app is working when I try it from RStudio IDE, but it is not when I deploy the app on the server.
The error is :

```
Error: RStudio not running
Execution halted
```

But if I change the `odbc` connection to :

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 DSN = 'abc',
                 Database = 'xxx',
                 UID = "myuser",
                 PWD ="mypass"
)
```

The app will work properly.
Any Idea how that could fix to avoid using the username / pass in the code ?